# TypeError: QuerySet.annotate() received non-expression(s): 0.0 m

Tags: python, django, geospatial, geos

I'm trying to list places ordered by distance from user location, I get an error of empty query. my models are defined as this in models.py

```
class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, help_text="Unique ID for this particular shop across whole library")
    location = gis_models.PointField("longitude/latitude",
                                 geography=True, blank=False, null=True)

    #objects = gis_models.GeoManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name, 'location'


class User(AbstractUser):
"""User model."""

username = None
email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
maplocation = gis_models.PointField("longitude/latitude", geography=True, blank=False, null=True)
```

and in my views.py I tried to do :

```
@login_required
def home(request):
    """
    View function for home page.
    """
    place_list = Place.objects.all()
    user = User.objects.get(email=request.user)
    ref_location = user.maplocation

    place_ordered = (Place.objects.annotate(distance=D(('location', ref_location)))
                                  .order_by('distance'))

    return render(
        request,
        'home.html',
        context={'place_list':place_list, 'place_ordered': place_ordered},
    )
```

and when I try to open my web page I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "~/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "~/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)/home/mohammed
File "~/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "~/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "~/Projects/Place/place_nearby/views.py", line 26, in home
place_ordered = Place.objects.annotate(distance=D(('location', ref_location))).order_by('distance')
File "~/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "~/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 971, in annotate
self._validate_values_are_expressions(args + tuple(kwargs.values()), method_name='annotate')
File "~/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1247, in _validate_values_are_expressions
', '.join(invalid_args),
TypeError: QuerySet.annotate() received non-expression(s): 0.0 m.
[05/Apr/2018 19:52:47] "GET /shops_nearby/ HTTP/1.1" 500 94837
```

Comment: Please include the error exactly as returned in the text format, it could help answering the question.

Comment: @AdrianoMartins, Thnak you, I added the whole error text

Comment: What is `D()` ?

Comment: it's an alias for Distance  from django.contrib.gis.measure import Distance as D

Comment: It seems you want the [DB model Distance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/gis/functions/#distance), and not `measure.Distance`.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida, many thanks, it solved the problem. I used:    from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import Distance as D <br/> and used D() not D((..))